# open Colorbox from text link

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr, colorbox

[EDITED QUESTION]

I am using an image preview tooltip, which is making use of the rel attribute, so for the colorbox i am using the class="slideshow" to group the images together.  I have this working fine, but i'd like to be able to open the slideshow from a text link, seen below.

(rel="medium.jpg" is the image used for the image preview)

```
<div id='gallery'>
      <a  href='large.jpg' class="slideshow" rel='medium.jpg'><img src='small.jpg'/></a>
      <a  href='large2.jpg' class="slideshow" rel='medium2.jpg'><img src='small.2jpg'/></a>
    </div>

<!--text link-->
<a href="#" class="openSlideshow">open slideshow</a>
```

Below is the standard code to trigger the colorbox, how can i modify this to open the slideshow?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("a.openSlideshow").colorbox({slideshow:true});
            });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you missed the ID - see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

I looked at colorbox page and everything is explained here.

Look at this, it's exactly what you are trying to do : [example 1](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm when I try Kai's suggestion it does not work

Using the example page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
  $("a.example4").colorbox({ slideshow: true });


    <h2>Slideshow</h2>
    <p><a href="../content/ohoopee1.jpg" class="example4"  title="Me and my grandfather on the Ohoopee.">Grouped Photo 1</a></p>
    <p><a href="../content/ohoopee2.jpg" class="example4"  title="On the Ohoopee as a child">Grouped Photo 2</a></p>
    <p><a href="../content/ohoopee3.jpg" class="example4"  title="On the Ohoopee as an adult">Grouped Photo 3</a></p>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am not using the rel, i am using class="" to group the images.

Comment: DOH. a.slideshow being the class selector...

so did you try Kai's suggestion?

Works for me when I change the example page - see my modified answer

Answer (score 0):

Just extend it after dynamically creating the gallery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            //dynamacially create the gallery here

            $("a.slideshow").colorbox({ slideshow: true });
        })
```